# js .off() is not working on <tr> elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, unbind

I have a table with `<tr>` having ew `<input>` elements with `onchange` event declared at design time but filled dynamically from database. The HTML of the `<td >` looks like this:-

```
<td scope="col" style="width: 60px; font-weight: normal;">
  <input type="text" id="hall_name" name="hall_name" class="form-control" onchange="rowEdited($(this).parent())" value=<%=hallName %> ></input>
</td>
<td scope="col" style="width: 50px; font-weight: normal; text-align: center">
  <input type="text" style="text-align: center" id="hall_capacity" name="hall_capacity" onchange="rowEdited($(this).parent())" class="form-control" value=<%=hallCapacity %>></input>
</td>
<td scope="col" style="width: 75px; font-weight: normal; text-align: center">
  <input type="text" id="hall_location" name="hall_location" onchange="rowEdited($(this).parent())" class="form-control" value=<%=hallLocation%>></input>
</td>
```

After cloning the last `<tr>`, I am attempting to remove the `onchange` events from all inputs in the last `<tr>` but it is not working.

The js code to clone the last `<tr>` looks like this:-

```
var row = $('#hallTable tr:last');
var new_row =  $(row).clone(false,false).off();
```

The Javascript codes I attempted until now are like this

```
$('#hallTable tr:last').find("*").off();
```

and

```
$('#hallTable tr:last').find(':input').each(function(){
    $(this).unbind('onchange', rowEdited);
})

$('#hallTable tr:last').find('input:checkbox').each(function(){
    $(this).unbind('onchange', rowEdited);
```

and

```
    $('#hallTable tr:last').find('input').onchange = null;
```

and

```
$('#hallTable tr:last').find('input').unbind('onchange', 'rowEdited');
```

But none are working. Please advise.

Comment: You should tag your question with `jquery`. `off` is not a standard javascript function.

Comment: Also add how the event handlers were *added*, since there are many ways this could have been done (jQuery, non-jQuery? Event-delegation?) What does "at design time" mean concretely (please add code)?

Comment: Could you provice a jsFiddle or other way to test your code?

Comment: Elaborated further details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) or `unbind` functions remove only event listeners that have been added using jQuery. They won't remove inline event listners  (like `onchange="rowEdited($(this).parent())"`).

To remove the inline event listner `onchange` for all ements that match `$('#hallTable tr:last').find('input')` you would need to write:

```
$('#hallTable tr:last').find('input').each(function() {
  this.onchange = null;
})
```

In general you should not use inline events at all. Either use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) or if you want to use jQuery then use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 1):

Since the event handling code is attached via `onclick` attributes, you should remove those attributes:

```
$('#hallTable tr:last input').removeAttr('onclick');
```

Note that this way you don't have to loop.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. Please try.

```
$('#hallTable tr:last').find('input').each(function (id, item) {
        item.onchange = null;
});
```

Should work regardless if the event is added via attributes or programmatically.